# Download ~50 million records from Teradata to Spark Delta table in Databricks daily efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, teradata

I am writing an ELT process in Databricks which will be downloading around 50 million records everyday and the table will have a year worth of data only. I optimized the query the best I could. The data is in Teradata database. I ran the EXPLAIN to see how long it will take. Mostly it shows only up to 10 minutes but when I run the query in Databricks to download the data in spark dataframe, and eventually to delta table then it takes almost all day.

I can't use the date column as a partition because each ELT process will be downloading 1 day's worth of data. I am thinking to use any other column.

```
sales_query = f""" SQL Query """

for x in range(0, 10):
  connection_error = False
  print(' Attempt #' + str(x+1))
  try:
    sales = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url", database_connection)
        .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
        .option("fetchsize","1000000") 
        .option("query", sales_query)
        # .option("partitionColumn","sales_date")  
        # .option("lowerBound", f'{start_date}')
        # .option("upperBound", f'{end_date}')
        # .option("numPartitions", 8)
        .load())
    break
  except Exception as connection_error:
    print('Query Failed. Reason ' + str(connection_error) + '\n' + 'Retrying...')
    sleep(sleep_time)
```

This above only takes 20 seconds which does not make sense to me, but I was told that here it only downloads the metadata instead of all the data (50 million records).

```
sales.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema","true").save(f"{project_path}/{level}/{delta_file_name}")
```

Is there anyway I can fasten this data extraction? I am not very much familiar with Databricks cluster but here is some info about the cluster I am using if it helps.

12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)

1-2 Workers
64-128 GB Memory
8-16 Cores
1 Driver
64 GB Memory, 8 Cores
Runtime
12.2.x-scala2.12

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](https://dzlab.github.io/spark/2022/02/10/spark-jdbc-partitioning/).  You can synthesise the column used by hashing over most fields (provided hash algo and approach is the same).

Or to use upper and lower bounds by using the limit - using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320647/1028537) as a base your predicates could add:

```sql
QUALIFY RowNum_ BETWEEN $start and $startplusstep;
```

(also you probably don't want .mode("overwrite") that won't keep other days results let alone a year).

Comment: Thanks Chris. This answer looks very promising. Let me try and I will update you here.

Comment: I was able to fasten the process using the partition method as mentioned in the article and the other stackoverflow solution. Thanks again Chris. It only took 1.5 hours this time

Comment: Glad to see such a drop in time, nice!